# Unique Values Separated by Line Break Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data that looks like this:

[image]

On some lines the product number is separated by a line break or 'Alt+Enter' in Excel.
I need to compile a list of unique values found in this column but am having trouble with the line breaks. I've tried using `=UNIQUE(S:S)` which works well but is unable to differentiate the products separated by a line break in a single cell. Using this formula gets me:

[image]

Where multiple product numbers are combined on the same line. Is there a way for me to manipulate this formula so it recognizes the line breaks? TYIA

Comment: Yes, it's possible but it would depend how many values you have in your data to figure out if a formula is the right solution to this problem.

Comment: I currently have 325 cells with data in them (including cells with multiple product numbers), but I'd like to be able to apply the formula to the entire column so as I add to it I get updated results

Comment: What version of Excel have you got?

Comment: Version 2202 Build 16.0.14931.20118

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant to say you have Excel ms365, a way to do this through formulae is to use `FILTERXML()`. However it would require `TEXTJOIN()`, and knowing you have 325 cells of potentially large quantities of elements this may exceed the character limits. I will nonetheless give you the idea outlined:

[image]

Formula in `C6`:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,A1:A6),CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[not(preceding::*=.)]")
```

Formula in `D6`:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,A1:A6),CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))
```